# How to select one of a group of element using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<img style="cursor: pointer" src="../common/images/plus.jpg"/> View History($revisions)
```

How to select the image button above? I want to select image with a source of

> ../common/images/plus.jpg

and of course the image must be clickable.

I added

```
<script>
$("img[src=../common/images/plus.jpg]").click(function(){
    alert("ok");
});
</script>
```

However, I got an error

> expected identifier or string for
>   value in attribute selector but found
>   '.'

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to select by src this should do it:

```
$('[src=../common/images/plus.jpg]')
```

... but you'd be better off giving it an ID - this is more reliable and faster.

```
<img id="imgPlus" style="cursor: pointer" src="../common/images/plus.jpg"/> View History($revisions)
```

then to select it you could just say:

```
$('#imgPlus')
```

Comment: A slightly more flexible alternative would be $('[src$="common/images/plus.jpg"]').  That just matches the suffix of the src attribute rather than the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can use a CSS3 attribute selector to find the image:

```
$('img[src="../common/images/plus.jpg"]').click(function() {
  //handle click event here
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oops. You need to add quotes around the URL like so. $('img[src="../common/images/plus.jpg"]').  Check out this article for more information: http://forabeautifulweb.com/blog/about/image_management_naming_and_attribute_selectors/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to provide the image with an id like

```
<img id="imgClick" style="cursor: pointer" src="../common/images/plus.jpg" />
```

and you can code like this

```
$("#imgClick").click(function(){
});
```